# Can Action.ToString() return anything other than "System.Action"?

Tags: c#, action, tostring

I'm programming in Unity, using an Action event to hold a bunch of other Action delegates, in order to hook non-Monobehaviour objects into the Update() system. I'd like to be able to print the names of the actions to the Debug console, but using something like:

```
Delegate[] actions = updateActions.GetInvocationList();
foreach ( Delegate del in actions ) {
    Debug.Log( del.ToString() );
}
```

... just returns "System.Action". I've tried also (del as Action).ToString() with no luck.

Comment: What is `name of the action`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Method` property to get a `MethodInfo` which should have a useful name.

```
Delegate[] actions = updateActions.GetInvocationList();
foreach ( Delegate del in actions )
{
    Debug.Log( del.Method.ReflectedType.FullName + "." + del.Method.Name );
}
```

You can use `del.Method.ToString()` if you want the signature or `del.Method.Name` if you only want the name. `del.Method.ReflectedType.FullName` gives you the type name.

For lambdas/anonymous methods the name might not be too useful since they only have a compiler generated name. In the current implementation the name of a lambda is something like `<Main>b__0` where `Main` is the name of the method that contains the lambda. Together with the type name this should give you a decent idea which lambda it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you declare a delegate

```
var foo = new Action(() => { /* do something */ });
```

and you want to retrieve the word "foo" later, you're out of luck.  To get that behavior you'll have to consume the declaration as an expression tree and parse out `foo` yourself.

Comment: What if I want to get (for debug purposes) the part `() => { /* do something */ }`?

Comment: You can't get the exact text (e.g. the comment) but you can assign that lambda to an `Expression<Action>` and get out the AST. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx for a basic overview.